# PPC clrlwi command - is the value digit included in the mask?

Tags: assembly, endianness, powerpc

I'm reading some code in PPC 750 Big-endian and not clear on the clear statement.

```
clrlwi.   r12, r12, 28
```

Is it: 
Clear to the Left of bit 28 (leaving 28,29,30,31) 
-or- 
Clear Left including bit 28 (leaving 29,30,31)?

I've read the PPC docs I have, did my best with Google search but can't find anything that makes this... "clear" to me. (bad pun, I know.)

Comment: You could always try it in a PPC simulator.  `qemu-ppc` can act as a gdb server, but I think you do need a gdb compiled to know about ppc code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instruction is a simplified form of [`rlwinm`](http://www.ds.ewi.tudelft.nl/vakken/in101/labcourse/instruction-set/rlwinm.html), which generates a mask from `MB` to `ME`, inclusive. `MB` in this case is 28 and `ME` is always 31 for `clrlwi`, so the mask will contain bits from 28 to 31, inclusive.

This is logical. If the bit selected wasn't included you could never select the full range from 0 to 31 and would always be masking away at least one bit from the result.

More information about the masks can be found from [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_53/com.ibm.aix.aixassem/doc/alangref/fixed_rotate_shift32.htm%23tlmrh331jeff?lang=fi).